# Extracting pixel values in satellite images using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat-8, clip, value-list

I'm trying to extract the pixel values(intensity values) of Landsat-8 satellite images using ArcGIS, I have an image and a crop data layer(CDL).

[image: CDL layer, each color represent different crop]

Then I only kept the data for one crop, and got the following result
[image: only one crop]

Now I want to know pixel intensity for these selected areas on the original satellite image.

I combined images together and  use "Pixel Inspector" to see the values.

But I want to have all the values, so I can then analyse them and find some specific values like max or min.

What I need is the pixel intensity in the satellite image but only in those areas which are highlighted with green in "green and white Image" , so I need to find the location of those green areas then go to satellite image and find the intensity value in the corresponding location.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you require. What do you mean by "I combined the images together"? And what values do you need "all" of? Are you simply trying to find the max and min of the crop corresponding to the green pixels?

Comment: What I need is the pixel intensity in the satellite image but only in those areas which are highlighted with green in "green and white Image" , so I need to find the location of those green areas then go to satellite image and find the intensity value in the corresponding location.

Comment: Try reclassifying the green and white to 1 (green) and 0 (white).  Multiply (raster calculator) each band of the satellite image by the 1,0 layer, and you will have values where the green was and zeroes elsewhere.   Or you could use NoData instead of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Zonal Statistics.  You can get max, min, mean, etc. for polygons or raster classes.  The real question is do you know what the source imagery was?  Which particular bands are you interested in? How do you plan on using this info?